# getRootNode() is not a function

Tags: extjs

I try to develop an app with MVC architecture. I've the following Controller code:

```
Ext.define('PM.controller.Projects', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models: ['Project'],
    stores: ['Projects'],

    views: [
        'projects.Tree',
        'Toolbar',
    ],

    init: function(config) {
        var tree = this.getProjectsTreeView();
        var rootNode = tree.getRootNode();
        console.log(rootNode);
        this.callParent(config);
    }
});
```

And this view code:

```
Ext.define('PM.view.projects.Tree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype: 'projectsTree',

    title: 'Projects',
    hideHeaders: true,
    root: {
        text: "Projekte"
    }

});
```

It try to get the root node from my tree view in the controller but I get the error that getRootNode() is not a valid function in my controller. Can anybody tell me why I get this error? My target is to add new children to this root node from an ajax request.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your tree var isn't undefined?

Comment: console.log(tree); outputs "construct()"

Comment: where is implementation of getProjectsTreeView()? I think you have to put a ref 'projectsTreeView' into your controllor.

Comment: I thought that was a magic method from the controller, wasn't it?

Comment: Well then there's your problem. But to be honoust, why are you accessing the rootNode on init of your controller? There's better palces to handle that stuff.

Comment: Where are these places? I want to add nodes from the server combined with static children. What is the selector for my tree? The view file is views/projects/Tree.js

Comment: Getters and setters will be set for every ref entry, but you have to set them by your own. And also keep in mind, that ref only make sense if component is singleton.

Comment: What is my selector for the tree view panel? When I use xtype the tree variable is undefined. What will be the correct method to implement these logic?

Answer (score 0):

The methods Ext generates for each string in the views array return constructors that can be used to create the respective views. That seems bizarre, but that's how it is.

If you want to access the actual view component, you'll need to create a `ref` for it. Your `init` method should not assume that the view exists yet. It's very likely that it won't since the controller's `init` method is called before the application's `launch` method which is probably where all the views are getting added to the page.

You want to put your logic in the controller's `onLaunch` template method which is called after the application has been launched and your view has been added.

```
Ext.define('PM.controller.Projects', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [{
        ref: 'projectsTreeView',
        selector: 'projectsTree'
    }],

    init: function() {
        // It's safe to add selectors for views that don't exist yet.
        this.control(/*...*/)
    },

    onLaunch: function(config) {
        var tree = this.getProjectsTreeView();
        var rootNode = tree.getRootNode();
        console.log(rootNode);
    }
});
```

If this doesn't work, that means you aren't actually adding your view anywhere. One place you could add it is in the application's launch method. Something has to add the treeview.

```
Ext.application({
    // ...

    views: ['projects.Tree']

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [new this.getProjectsTreeView()]
        });
    }
});
```

So the chronology of events is this:

```
Application#constructor 
Controller#constructor
Controller#init (can't assume the view exists)
Application#onBeforeLaunch
Application#launch (view is now added)
Controller#onLaunch (do something with the view that is now available)
```

Also, your view alias may need to be `'widget.projectsTree'` not just `'projectsTree'`.